# index.js doesn't see node module on import

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-package

My project didn't have `package.json` earlier, but now I have to add npm packages to the site.

I typed in project root directory `npm init`, after `npm i moment` and package has been installed, but **index.js** file doesn't see it, so this code `import moment from 'moment';` returns me an error:

```
dex.html:1 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "moment". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

which probably means that it tries to receive export from the file.

So I decided to manually provide the whole path to the file as `../../node_modules/moment/moment.js`, but **moment.js** doesn't have export at all.

Anyway I would needed to add Node.js to the project, as I'm going to connect site via express, so it has to be added correctly

**Update based on @Nonik's comment:** I tried to use `const moment = require('moment');` but it returns me:

```
dex.js:11 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

My main file is **index.html**

Here is the [repo](https://github.com/ZakharovVladyslav/KATEK-Project/tree/testing)

Comment: have you tried var moment = require('moment');

Comment: @Nonik check question update please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use some form of bundler, like [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/). Node.js may load files from the filesystem, but a web browser has no concept of a "module" or "exports" (pre-ESM, that is). A bundler is a separate build step which integrates Webpack's code with your own code that is possible to use on the web.

You can also use a `script` tag or ESM to import directly from a CDN like unpkg.

Comment: Actually in my case with `Moment.js` I just decided to use CDN, but your answer seemed to be the most accurate

Answer (score 0):

> if you are building a backend project with nodejs then use common js module like following

```
const moment = require("moment")
```

Comment: Please pay attention on my question where I noticed that `require` doesn't work